# Salesforce Error: Getting content from within triggers is currently not supported

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I am trying to update existing code (written by someone else, and I am not a developer - just trying to help a friend out) so that it uses 'files' instead of the old 'attachments'.

The trigger is to: when the criteria is met on the Opportunity, send out an email and include a related file from the opportunity.

When I test it, I get the following error: 
**sendAttachments: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.VisualforceException: Getting content from within triggers is currently not supported. Trigger.sendAttachments: line 172, column 1**

I have found with a google search that it can be resolved if you use "@future(callout=true) annotation before the method".  Doesn't matter where I put this in the code - I can't get it to compile without errors.  Wondering if it is because the logic is all in the trigger instead of the class? 
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
trigger  sendAttachments on Opportunity (after update,after insert) {
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){

        if(opp.Ready_for_Billing__c == true &&  opp.SenttoBilling__c == false){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            opp = [SELECT id, account.name,account.parent.name, bundledamt__c,SO_Number__c, IO_Number__c, OwnerId, Type, Contract_Start_Date__c, Expiration_Date__c,    
                   Is_Insertion_Order__c, StageName, Note_to_Billing__c, Purchase_Order_Number__c,Billing_Country__c, Billing_Contact__c, Billing_Address__c, Bill_Email__c, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
            User u = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :opp.OwnerId];
            Contact DC = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :'Delivery-Invoices'];
            Contact MC = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :'Media-Invoices'];  
            Contact CC = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :'CC-Invoices']; 
            String Name;

            if (opp.Is_Insertion_Order__c == True){
                Name = opp.IO_Number__c;
            }
             else{
                Name = opp.SO_Number__c;
            } 
            String AccName = opp.account.name;                
            String subject;
            String repname = u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName; 
            String ordertype;
            String owneremail = u.Email;
            String notes = opp.Note_to_Billing__c;
            String othernotes;


            if( (opp.Billing_Country__c == 'India') || (opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Egypt')||(opp.Billing_Country__c == 'China')||(opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Pakistan' ) ||
              (opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Indonesia') || (opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Viet Nam')||(opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Thailand')||(opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Malaysia' ) ||
              (opp.Billing_Country__c == 'United Arab Emirates') || (opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Singapore')||(opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Poland')||(opp.Billing_Country__c == 'Romania' )){
                othernotes = 'IMPORTANT: Note that invoice is going to a country that may withhold taxes. Refer to history'+'\r\n';
              }else{
                  othernotes = '';
              }


            // create email content
            if (opp.Type == null){
                ordertype = 'Not Available';
            }
            else{
                ordertype = opp.Type;
            } 

            String contractdates;
            if (opp.Contract_Start_Date__c == null){
                if(opp.Expiration_Date__c == null){
                    contractdates = 'Not Available';
                }
                else{
                    contractdates = 'Expiration date - '+ opp.Expiration_Date__c.month()+ '/' + opp.Expiration_Date__c.day() +'/' +opp.Expiration_Date__c.year();
                }
            }
            else{
                if(opp.Expiration_Date__c == null){
                    contractdates = 'Start Date - ' + opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.month()+'/'+opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.day()+'/'+  opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.year();
                }
                else{
                    contractdates = opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.month()+'/'+opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.day()+'/'+  opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.year()+' - ' + opp.Expiration_Date__c.month()+'/'+opp.Expiration_Date__c.day()+'/'+opp.Expiration_Date__c.year();
                }
            } 
            subject = 'Ready for Billing: SO/IO '+Name+ ' for ' + AccName;
            List<String> ccaddress;
            if (CC != Null){
                ccaddress = new List<String>{CC.Email, owneremail};
                    }
            Else{
                ccaddress = new List<String>{owneremail};
                    }

            email.setSubject(subject);

            String salutation = 'Hello Accounting, '+  '\r\n'+  '\r\n';
            String line1 = 'A New order is ready to be billed: '+  '\r\n';
            String line2;
            if (opp.Is_Insertion_Order__c == False){
                line2 = '   SO #: ' + Name +  '\r\n';
            }
            else{
                line2 = '   IO #: ' + Name +  '\r\n';
            } 

            String line3 = '   Account: '+AccName+ '\r\n';
            String line4;
            if (opp.Is_Insertion_Order__c == False){
                line4 = '   Order Type (renewal/upsell/new): '+ ordertype + '\r\n';
            }
            else{
                line4 = '\r\n';
            } 

            String line5 = '   Contract Dates: '+ contractdates + '\r\n'+ '\r\n'; 
            String line6 = '\r\n'+ '\r\n'+ 'Regards,' + '\r\n';       
            String line7 = repname + '\r\n' + '\r\n';
            String body = salutation + line1 + line2 + line3 + line4+ line5; 
            string BillingNotes;
            string BillingNotes2;
            if (opp.Is_Insertion_Order__c == True){
                if ( opp.Purchase_Order_Number__c != Null){
                    BillingNotes2 = 'Include PO#: ' + opp.Purchase_Order_Number__c + '\r\n';
                }
                else{
                    BillingNotes2 ='\r\n';
                }

                if( opp.Billing_Contact__c != Null) {
                    Contact bc = [SELECT Name  FROM Contact WHERE Id = :opp.Billing_Contact__c];
                    BillingNotes = 'Bill To: ' + bc.Name + '\r\n';
                    BillingNotes = BillingNotes + '         ' + opp.Bill_Email__c + '\r\n';
                    if ( opp.Purchase_Order_Number__c != Null){
                        BillingNotes = BillingNotes2 + BillingNotes;
                    }
                }
                if( opp.Billing_Address__c != Null) {
                    if( opp.Billing_Contact__c != Null){
                        BillingNotes = BillingNotes + '         ' + opp.Billing_Address__c.replaceAll('<br>',', ') + '\r\n' + '\r\n';
                    }
                    else {
                        BillingNotes = 'Billing Address: ' + opp.Billing_Address__c.replaceAll('<br>',', ') + '\r\n' + '\r\n';
                    }
                }
                else{
                    BillingNotes = BillingNotes + '\r\n' + '\r\n';
                }
            }

            if (opp.Note_to_Billing__c != Null){

                string cleannotes = opp.Note_to_Billing__c.replaceAll('<br>','\r\n');
                cleannotes = cleannotes.replaceAll('<[^>]+>',' ');
                if (BillingNotes != Null){
                    BillingNotes = othernotes + '\r\n' + BillingNotes + cleannotes;
                }
                else{
                    BillingNotes = othernotes + '\r\n' + cleannotes;
                }
                body = body + 'Notes: '+ '\r\n' + BillingNotes;
            }
            if (opp.bundledamt__c > 0){
                OpportunityLineItem[] bundledItems = [SELECT Id, Opportunityid, PricebookEntry.Name, TotalPrice, Quantity, UnitPrice, Description, Bundled__c
                                                      from OpportunityLineItem where (Bundled__c =: 'Yes'  AND Opportunityid =: opp.Id) ];
                body = body + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + 'Breakdown of bundled products:' + '\r\n';

                for (OpportunityLineItem oli : bundledItems){
                    body = body + oli.Quantity.round() + ' ' + oli.PricebookEntry.Name + ' (' + oli.Description + '); Price: ' + oli.UnitPrice+ '; Total: ' + oli.TotalPrice + '\r\n';
                }
            }

            body = body + line6+ line7;

            email.setPlainTextBody(body);

            if(opp.Is_Insertion_Order__c == true){
                email.setToAddresses(new String[]{MC.Email});
            }
            else if( opp.account.parent.name == 'XXX Group' &&  (opp.Contract_Start_Date__c.daysBetween(opp.Expiration_Date__c))<32) {
                email.setToAddresses(new String[]{MC.Email});
            }
            else{
                email.setToAddresses(new String[]{DC.Email});
            }
            email.setCcAddresses(ccaddress);

            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
            PageReference pref = page.attachIOPDFforBilling;
            /*for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :opp.Id]){
                Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();*/
                for (ContentDocumentLink a : [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId  FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=: opp.id]){
                Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                //efa.setFileName(a.Title);
                efa.setBody(pref.getContentAsPDF());
                fileAttachments.add(efa);
            }
            email.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);// Send email
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because it's just a block of code in a trigger. It's against best practices, ideally you'd have some handler class in there with "meat" of the logic and trigger would have just few lines to call it.

If you want to change as little as possible you can still do it in 1 file. It looks absolutely crazy but you can have main code in a trigger and methods defined in it.

Take a backup of the current code and try with structure similar to this (I'm not saying it's perfect, might not compile, there might be typos. And there are performance issues like "query in a loop" (pulling info about the user that owns this opportunity - it might work fine for single records but it'll crash and burn if you mass insert ~20 opps at same time.... sorry, you might need a programmer to do it right and maybe cough up some $ for professional services look into this code and decide what's best.

```
trigger  sendAttachments on Opportunity (after update,after insert) {
    Set<Id> opportunitiesToSend = new Set<Id>();
    for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(opp.Ready_for_Billing__c == true &&  opp.SenttoBilling__c == false){
            opportunitiesToSend.add(opp.Id);
        }
    }
    if(!opportunitiesToSend.isEmpty()){
        sendEmails(opportunitiesToSend);
    }

    // it looks insane but it works, a method defined straight in a trigger.
    // to do it properly - you should have another class you're calling
    @future (callout=true)
    static void sendEmails(Set<Id> opportunityIds){
        Map<Id, Opportunity> opps = [SELECT id, account.name,account.parent.name, 
            bundledamt__c,SO_Number__c, IO_Number__c, OwnerId, Type, Contract_Start_Date__c, 
            Expiration_Date__c, Is_Insertion_Order__c, StageName, Note_to_Billing__c,
            Purchase_Order_Number__c,Billing_Country__c, Billing_Contact__c, 
            Billing_Address__c, Bill_Email__c, Name 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Id IN :opportunityIds]);
        for(Id i : opportunityIds){
            opp = opps.get(i);
            // put rest of the code here
            User u = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM User WHERE Id = :opp.OwnerId];
            Contact DC = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :'Delivery-Invoices'];
            Contact MC = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :'Media-Invoices'];  
            Contact CC = [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = :'CC-Invoices']; 
            String Name;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```